# Ubuntu Server, Third Party Package Install

Tags: server

I have installed Ubuntu server 16.04.3 LTS. I know that I could install a GUI package in order to simplify the problem of installing a third-party program/package/driver et. al. However, I much prefer the tty1 environment, especially since this particular blackbox is going to be used for research.

Will anyone in the community either demonstrate or direct me to a step-by-step guide for downloading and installing a package from a non-specific or variable website?

Thank you in advance to all those who may offer up insight.

Edit: I want to get a package from a specific URL using the server interface: how do I download, unzip, and install the package?

Comment: That is a vast question. Do you specifically want to know how to install a .deb package? A snap package? A flatpack? An AppImage? A pip package? Or some other kind of "program/package/driver". Please narrow the scope of your question, lest it be closed as too broad.

Comment: Also, the vast majority of packages in any distribution's main archive, are _third party_.

Comment: Thanks, you're correct; my question is far too broad. Let me narrow it down: I want to get a package from a specific URL; so using the server interface, how do I download, unzip, and install the package?

Comment: download a package using your favorite tool (`wget`for me) .. then the next step varies depending upon the type of 'package' downloaded.  if its a .deb you don't need to expand as a `dpkg -i` will install it (assuming all dependencies exist on machine), a `apt install ./` will use dpkg to install adding deps if they exist in your sources.list file. if deps are not in your sources.list you'll need to wget them and install them first. if it's a tarball .....   (your question is still very broad!)

Answer (score 1):

On your computer, go to the website where the `.deb` file is located, right click and select copy link address on the download link/button. Then, on your server, run

```
wget link
```

Or, if you have cURL installed:

```
curl -O link
```

The file should now be in your local folder. 
If the file is compressed, simply uncompress it with:
If it's a zip file use

```
unzip file.zip
```

Otherwise, it's probably a tar file, so

```
tar xzvf file.tar.gz
```

Next, all you have to do is install the package, which can be done with

```
sudo dpkg -i filename.deb
```

Before you install `deb` files, be sure to check if you can install from a repository first, as then you just use

```
sudo apt install package
```

Comment: What if the downloaded file is a tar.xz file?

Comment: Just updated my answer.

Comment: I accidentally submitted my comment before qualifying my follow-up question. I have installed the tar file to my downloads directory using wget, but I still don't understand how to use the given commands to extract a tar.xz file. Will you please spell it out for me, as I do not understand. The output-string following the download reads 'filename.tar.xz' saved [54833/54833]

Comment: What happens when you run `tar xzvf filename.tar.xz`

Comment: I get the string-output: "tar (child): filename.tar.xz: Cannot open: No such file or directory."

Comment: That means that `filename.tar.xz` does not exist. Does it appear in `ls`?

Comment: Yes, it appears.

Answer (score 1):

Use `wget` in case its really outside the Ubuntu world (you might need to install it via `sudo apt install wget`):

```
cd <download-location>
wget http://url/...
```

Use `dpkg` to install `.deb` files:

```
dpkg -i debfile.deb
```

You can use apt to install packages to:

```
apt install package-name
```

On newer versions of ubuntu you can even install `.deb` files with it.

```
apt install debfile.deb
```

Use `tar` to extract `.tar.gz` or similar files

```
tar -xf archive.tar.gz
```

Use `p7zip` for `.7z` or `.zip` files (afaik theres even .rar capability in a secondary package available, you might need to install it with `sudo apt install p7zip p7zip-full p7zip-rar`):

```
7z x archive.7z
```

In case you downloaded source code you need to compile it, refer to the README file for how to do that.

Additional you can use links, links2 and lynx as command-line browsers (all of em are available in the Ubuntu repositories).

Comment: I think I'm beginning to understand. I used wget link to acquire the file. I didn't specify a location because I don't know how.

Comment: You not need to specify a location, this is why i phrased it vague as `cd <download-location>` mean it will get downloaded to the directory you're currently at. If you wan to keep it organized you want to switch to a directory of your choice by using `cd my_download_directory` for example.